# How to create custom SwiftUI binding with different type for Binding and for display?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

According to [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-custom-bindings) article it should be simple to create custom Binding with different type for binding and for display. This is my not working example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BindingButton: View {
    @Binding var title: String
    var onTap: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            onTap()
        } label: {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomBinding: View {
    @State var date: Date
    @State var int: Int
    
    lazy var descriptiveDate = Binding(
        get: { //Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter
            return self.date.description
        },
        set: { _ in }
    )
    
    lazy var descriptiveInt = Binding(
        get: { //Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter
            return String(self.int)
        },
        set: { _ in }
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Cannot find '$descriptiveDate' in scope
            BindingButton(title: $descriptiveDate) {
                date = Date()
            }
            // Cannot find '$descriptiveInt' in scope
            BindingButton(title: $descriptiveInt) {
                int += 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to bind Date and Int, but use string for display. Is it possible witohut Double Binding? I mean I would like to avoid to create first Binding for Date and Int, then `.onChange` update another Binding for String and String. Do I have to do it like this, or maybe there is more elegant way?

Comment: Why you need a binding for your button title? A binding is needed only when you need to modify the state from a child component. Your `BindingButton` doesn't change anything in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` is by definition a two-way connection. `lazy` implies that the code only runs once. Based on this and the empty `set` your `descriptiveDate` and `descriptiveInt` don't need to be `Binding` just a `get` for a `String`

```
struct CustomBinding: View {
    @State var date: Date
    @State var int: Int
    
    var descriptiveDate: String {
        date.description
    }
            
    var descriptiveInt : String{
        String(self.int)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            BindingButton(title: descriptiveDate) {
                date = Date()
            }
            BindingButton(title: descriptiveInt) {
                int += 2
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BindingButton: View {
    let title: String
    var onTap: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            onTap()
        } label: {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
```

`lazy` doesn't work with with `SwiftUI` `View`s when `@State` triggers a redraw you need to recalculate the `body` and descriptive variables.

Comment: Thank you for your effort;) One additional question. When I change the date from `Button` on tap, will it change title of that button just like that? What will cause that title is updated?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk immediately, setting the date will cause a redraw

Comment: Ok, so for me it is the best solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the previous answer that in this case the binding is not needed. But to address the other part of the question: "Is it possible to have interdependent `@State` and `@Binding` without Double Binding?"

Well, first of all, even in the most primitive way, you don't need a custom binding. Instead you can use 2 state variables:

```
    @State var descriptiveDate: String
    @State var descriptiveInt: String
```

and utilize either `didSet`:

```
    @State var date: Date {
        didSet {
            descriptiveDate = date.description
        }
    }
    @State var int: Int {
        didSet {
            descriptiveInt = String(int)
        }
    }
    
    @State var descriptiveDate: String
    @State var descriptiveInt: String
```

Or have `onChange` implemented for `date` and `int` state:

```
struct CustomBinding: View {
    
    @State var date: Date
    @State var int: Int
    @State var descriptiveDate: String
    @State var descriptiveInt: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            BindingButton(title: $descriptiveDate) {
                date = Date()
            }
            .onChange(of: date) { newDate in
                descriptiveDate = newDate.description
            }
            BindingButton(title: $descriptiveInt) {
                int += 2
            }
            .onChange(of: int) { newInt in
                descriptiveInt = String(int)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

But this is still a bit redundant, as you will have duplication of the `@State` for every variable. So to avoid that custom binding is helpful:

```
            BindingButton(title: Binding(
                get: { int.description },
                set: { int = Int($0)! }
            )) {
                int += 2
            }
```

That is: you don't need to keep additional state for each state, while still have a possibility to change parent value from child. Doesn't make much sense in this concrete example, but it does in some cases.

So did we avoid "double" variable - not really. Since you have 2 pieces of information that can change following some rules, but independently, you do need 2 of something. But custom binding is just one of the possibilities.

Comment: Oh, that is quite pretty, I didnt know I can add `didSet` to `@State` property.